# state does not update even when i set the state in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

i'm facing an issue in which i'm trying to set default values for form using states but when i access the states below in form to filter out items i get an error filter is not a function. Even though some values are filled in form but when i submit it still says fields are required.

Expectation:
1- by setting properties in setState which are accessible in form but are not getting validate in form.
2- by setting properties in setField which stores column id with true/false values i'm unable to access them in form i recieved an error that filter is not a function.

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getLeadesColumns()).then((res) => {
        if (
            res.type === "forms/getLeadesColumns/fulfilled" &&
            formData.type === "Edit"
        ) {
            const { data } = res.payload.response;
            const filteredColumns =
                data.filter((column) => column.is_deleteable === "1") || [];

            const showCols = editForm.show_columns
                .split(",")
                .map((column) => parseInt(column));

            const updatedField = {};

            filteredColumns.forEach((column) => {
                updatedField[column.id] = showCols.includes(column.id);
            });

            setField({ ...field, ...updatedField });
            const showFields = JSON.parse(editForm.show_fields);
            setValue("name", editForm.name);
            setState({
                name: editForm.name,
                title: editForm.title,
                description: editForm.description,
                user_id: editForm.user_id,
            });
            setEmailRequired(showFields.email);
            setPhoneRequired(showFields.phone);
            setAddressRequired(showFields.address);
            setChecked(showFields?.notes);
        }
    });
}, [editForm]);
```

This is where i'm getting error for filter is not a function in CheckState :

```
{
    columns && columns.response?.data && (
        <div className="flex flex-wrap">
            {columns.response?.data
                .filter((column) => column.is_deleteable === "1")
                .map((column) => {
                    const checkState =
                        formData.type == "Edit"
                            ? field
                                  .filter((val) => val.id == true)
                                  .find((val) => val.id == column.id)
                            : false;
                    return (
                        <div
                            className="flex flex-row sm:flex-row justify-start"
                            style={{ width: "50%" }}
                            key={column.id}
                        >
                            <FormControlLabel
                                value={field[column.name]}
                                control={
                                    <Switch
                                        color="primary"
                                        onChange={() => handleCol(column)}
                                    />
                                }
                                // label={'Enable' + ' ' + column.name}
                                label={column.name}
                                // labelPlacement="top"
                            />
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
        </div>
    );
}
```

This is one of the required field which not validating even though the default value has been set in it:

```
<Select
    variant="outlined"
    id="workflow_id"
    color="primary"
    // value="Pipeline"
    required
    error={!!errors.workflow_id}
    helperText={errors?.workflow_id?.message}
    value={state.workflow_id}
    onChange={handleChange}
    inputProps={{
        name: "workflow_id",
        id: "workflow_id",
    }}
>
    {workflow &&
        workflow.response?.data.map((flow) => (
            <MenuItem
                className={classes.select}
                style={{
                    backgroundColor:
                        flow.id == state.workflow_id ? "green" : "",
                    color: flow.id == state.workflow_id ? "white" : "",
                }}
                value={flow.id}
                key={flow.id}
            >
                {flow.name}
            </MenuItem>
        ))}
</Select>;
```